# Octave dataframe's problem with isna() function

Tags: octave, isnull, octave-gui, isnan

I use Octave dataframe to read csv file but some columns can compute numbers of NA but some don't. How can I fix this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rg0Lr.png)

I suspect it is about the columns with char type that does not work. How can I fix this? I want to use Octave for data science practice too. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Input file is needed in order to debug this issue

Comment: It's in this kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/prashant111/logistic-regression-classifier-tutorial/notebook

Comment: It is just a link to some Web site. Where is the input file?

Comment: I don't understand what you meant? The name of it is 'weatherAUS.csv' in https://www.kaggle.com/prashant111/logistic-regression-classifier-tutorial/data

Comment: Yes, Octave dlmread does not support categorical values. I'd recommend to preprocess this file and replace all strings by some numbers. For example, wind direction may be replace by angle (N=0, E=90, S=180 etc.) Yes may be replace by 1 and No by zero. This may be easily done by using any programming language, spreadsheet application or text editor. It is also possible to write your own parser in Octave.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I should do that.